# kotlin - how to make a nullable boolean within a Parceable

Tags: kotlin, nullable, parcelable

Having a Parcelable class with a nullable boolean memembr default to null

could do it like

```
parcel.writeByte(if (isAllowed==null) -1 else (if (isAllowed) 1 else 0))
```

but how to get it back and pass it in the constractor?

Is there a better way to serialize/deserialize the nullable boolean?

```
  class Config(val isAllowed: Boolean?=null, val startPos: Int=-1 ) : Parcelable {
      constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
        parcel.readInt()


      override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
          parcel.writeByte(if (isAllowed) 1 else 0)
          parcel.writeInt(startPos)

      }
......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.let{}` to return the computed value.

```
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(parcel.readByte().let { if(it < 0) null else (it > 0) },parcel.readInt())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to create a `Config` from a `Parcel`, but it doesn't have to be a constructor even if most examples do that. In your `CREATOR`:

```
fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Config {
    val parcelByte = parcel.readByte()
    val isAllowed = if (parcelByte < 0) null else parcelByte > 0
    val startPos = parcel.readInt()
    return Config(isAllowed, startPos)
}
```

Obviously this can be extracted into `fun Parcel.read(write)NullableBoolean()` if you need it more than once.

Or just use [`@Parcelize`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable) :)